# Typescript imported class: Unsafe return of an `any` typed value

Tags: typescript

I'm relatively new to Typescript and don't have much familiarity with setting up the requisite environment; any help would be appreciated. I'm running to an issue with the below code:

models/Player.ts

```
export interface PlayerI {
  health: number
  resources: number
  turnsPlayed: number
  drawCard?: (card: Card) => void
}

export default class Player implements PlayerI {
  health: number
  resources: number
  turnsPlayed: number

  constructor() {
    this.health = 10000
    this.resources = 3000
    this.turnsPlayed = 0
  }
}
```

utils.ts

```
import Player, {PlayerI} from '@models/Player'

export function createPlayer(): PlayerI {
  return new Player()
}
```

This code gives me the error: `Unsafe return of an 'any' typed value.` in the `new Player()` portion.

However, if the code is all in one file, i.e no imports, there is no error.
I figure there's something in the typescript or eslint configuration somewhere that's incorrect but I've no ideas.

Edit: my tsconfig.json

```
{
 "compilerOptions": {
   "target": "es2016",                           
   "lib": ["es6"],                               
   "module": "commonjs",                         
   "rootDir": "src",                             
   "moduleResolution": "node",                   
   "baseUrl": "./src",                           
   "paths": {
     "@models/*": ["./models/*"],
     "@utils/*": ["./utils/*"],
   },                                            
   "resolveJsonModule": true,                    
   "allowJs": false,                             
   "outDir": "build",                            
   "esModuleInterop": true,                      
   "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,     
   "strict": true,                               
   "noImplicitAny": true,                        
   "skipLibCheck": true                          
 },
 "exclude": ["jest.config.ts"],
 "include": [
   "src/**/*"]
}
```

Comment: What is the reported type when you mouse over `Player` in `import Player`? Also, try to replicate the issue in https://codesandbox.io/ and add a link to your question.

Comment: Everything looks correct at first glance.  I don't see any violations of [the eslint rule](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-unsafe-return.md).

Comment: can you share your `tsconfig.json` ?

Comment: Added my tsconfig.json. When mousing over the import statement, it says: `(alias) class Player`

Answer (score -2):

I have this problem also:

`tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": "./",
    "baseUrl": "./lib"
  },
  "include": ["lib/**/*"]
}
```

`utils/format.ts`:

```
export default function format(text: string, ...args: string[]): string {
  return args.reduce((acc, arg, iArg) => acc.replace(new RegExp(`:\\{${iArg}\\}`, 'g'), arg), text);
}
```

and I am getting a error (`Unsafe call of an any typed value.eslint@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-call`) when I import this file here:

```js
import format from 'utils/format';

console.log('db-schema-builder say hello', format(':{0} :{1} !!!', 'Hello', 'World'));
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32845220)